# How to extract username from Http QueryString in logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault, azure-data-factory

I am sending query String as:

https://prod-17.westindia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/f3b63b086e61420e8d76b7478f4b3e39/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=nESqZWY2NyAKKhCkaM0VnfenHuTqi1NSBjJdl9M5jNA&UserName=SecretName&Password=Nikita@123

I want to extract UserName in logic app. For that I have used Compose connector and use following statement in expression.

coalesce(triggerOutputs()['queries']?['UserName'] , '**blank**')

I have tried this to::                                                                                                       triggerOutputs()['queries']?['UserName']

But I am getting one single blank space appended in front of UserName in output. Due to which, my condition is  becoming false even if UserName is correct.

How to remove this extra space which is unnecessary appending to front.

[image]

HTTP Connector Output as :

[image]

In this scenario , password is working fine. As below is output: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [trigger output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#pass-parameters-through-endpoint-url) and you should not use the **Coalesce expression**.